# Deleting the records from all relationships table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Questions hasmany Answers.
Answers hasmany Comments.
Comments hasmany Votes.
Answers hasmany Votes.

Now, if i delete a question, i want the question along with it's answers, and all the comments and votes on the answer to be deleted. What i have done looks not so elegant.

```
    $question=Question::where(['id'=>$request->id])->first();
    $answers=Answer::where(['q_id'=>$request->id])->get();
    foreach($answers as $answer)
    {
            $comments=Comment::where(['answer_id'=>$answer->id])->get();
            foreach($comments as $comment)
            {
                $votes=vote::where(['votable_id'=>$answer->id])
                            ->orWhere(['votable_id'=>$comment->id])
                            ->get();
                foreach($votes as $vote)
                {
                    $vote->delete();   
                }

                    $comment->delete();
             }

                $answer->delete();
   }
   $question->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's [oberservers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) for this. So your *deleting* methods could look like

```
public function deleting(Question $user)
{
    $question->answers()->delete();

    // Etc.
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boot method in your model at the time deletion.
  It will delete the all the relationship model data.

In your Question model, you need relationship functions for answer, comments and vote.

Now, you can use this.,

```
    protected static function boot()
    {
       parent::boot();
       static::deleting(function ($question) {
        $question->answers()->delete();
        $question->comments()->delete();
        $question->votes()->delete();
       });
    }
```

The relationship common mock is,

```
    public function name()        
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App/name', 'fk_id', 'p_id');
    }
```

If your deleting question in controller as usual and it will delete answer, comments and votes also.

```
    $question = Question::all()->delete();
```

Any doubts in relationship, use this for refer [laravel 5.2 relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)